# Whether a Pathological Set Might Exist that could Foil a Theorem about the Exponential Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function, exponentiation

There has been some discussion recently about the theorem

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{i = 1}^n \left( 1 + \frac{x_i}{n} \right)
= \exp \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i
\right)$$

and the grounds of it. At the beginning of this discussion, it was stipulated that the set ${x_j}$ be *bounded* ... and  I think this condition *surely must* ensure the holding of the theorem. But the question is this: what set ${x_j}$ might be devised that would *foil* this theorem? - a set such that it *does not* hold.

Comment: Actually, Im beginning to have doubts about asking this already, as I think that if the _x_j_ are increasing without limit as _n_ increases then that would violate it: at most they could grow as _n^ε_ with ε <1 ... or perhaps even no faster than ln(_n_)

Comment: If for some _m_ you had sum{j=1 to n}x_j^m ≠ o(n^m), that would be enough to foil the theorem. So for a set that has sum{j=1 to n}x_j^m = o(n^m) ∀m the thoreom would hold, though the set be unbounden.

Comment: Obviously the arithmetic mean of the set _must_ exist in the limit as n →∞ for the RHS to even _mean_ anything - it is one with the very _proviso_ of the theorem that this limit exists, which means that the set is _bounded_ which means that the set of any _power_ of the x_j is bounded, which means _it_ has a mean also. So given those conditions, I don't think now that a pathological set that foils the theorem _could_ exist, as in the expansion of the _logarithm_ of the LHS, all limits with n more than linear in the denominator would tend to zero, as with n _linear_ they would tend to a _mean_.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might be getting to the heart of what's been bugging me about this. I saw the question, & I devised a rather laboured combinatorial argument to show that the binomial expansion of the LHS *morphs into* the Taylor expansion for exponential on the RHS, *even when* the $x$ is an infinite set, one element per bracket on the LHS instead of a single value in *every* bracket, and the arithmetic mean of the set is substituted for the single value of $x$ on the RHS; and then I saw the proofs involving *taking the logarithm* of both sides, & expressing the logarithm as a Taylor series on the LHS; and I thought "how silly of me using that clumsy combinatorial method!": *but*! ... there was something about these logarithmic proofs that I *just kept noticing* in the periphery of my vision - and it is is that *none of them* when the LHS is developed as the taylor series of a logarithm **actually uses at *any point* the fact that it is particularly *the logarithm*** - the series could have prettymuch *any* coefficients, and the reasoning would be *exactly* the same!

Anyway, now, to my mind, the solution is this: that what this theorem is ultimately essentially saying is that *the exponential function is, essentially, the function that has the property that* $\operatorname{f}(x+y)\equiv\operatorname{f}(x)\operatorname{f}(y)$, *the property that* $\operatorname{f}(0)=1$, *and the property that* $\operatorname{f^\prime}(0)=1$. Of course we know that the exponential function *has* these properties: what I am saying is that the theorem that is the subject of this post (and of the other post mentioned) is *saying simply **that** ... just simply **that***.

You've got the sum $$\sum_{j=1}^n{x_j\over n}$$ and if this sum is finite in the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ you can forget about the higher degree terms, and it doesn't matter whether it's $\operatorname{log}(1+x)$ or $x/(1-x)$ or whatever it is as long as it goes through the origin, because by reason of each term in the sum having an $n$ that's going to infinity in the denominator its only the first derivative that counts anymore; and when it's exponentiated, by reason of the second & third properties of the exponential cited above, each term becomes $$\left(1+{x_j\over n}\right) ,$$ and by reason of the first property all these brackets become multiplied together.

Whence you arrive at the theorem that is the subject of this post ... & of that other.